# Doubts Regarding Proof Of Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

I was trying to understand the proof of Cauchy Integral formula from the book "Complex Analysis" By Stein and Shakarchi. I understand most steps of that proof, but I have one doubt:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I understand that due to Cauchy Integral Theorem, the integral of the domain bounded by the curve $C$ is 0, and this irrespectively of the value around the $|\zeta|=\epsilon$ part. However **in book they state that in the limit $\delta \to0$ the integral of $f(\zeta)/{(\zeta -z)}$ equals the one around the exterior circle part of $C$ plus the integral around the circle $|\zeta|=\epsilon$, and I do not get this part**.

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply a matter of what is the limiting value of 
$$
\oint_{\Gamma_{\epsilon,\delta}}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta,\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
calculated while keeping $\epsilon$ constant and letting $\delta\to 0$. The value of the curvilinear integral on the two parallel segments of $\Gamma_{\epsilon,\delta}$ has the following form
$$
\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta + \int_{z_2-\delta \xi_2}^{z_1-\delta \xi_1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta=\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta-\int_{z_1-\delta \xi_1}^{z_2-\delta \xi_2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
where $z_1,z_1-\delta\xi_1\in C_\epsilon$ and $z_2,z_2-\delta\xi_2\in C$: when $\delta\to 0$, \eqref{2} goes to $0$, therefore
$$
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\oint_{\Gamma_{\epsilon,\delta}}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta=\oint_C\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta- \oint_{C_\epsilon}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta\tag{3}\label{3}
$$
**Edit**: in order to explain the concept in a better way, I added the following picture:

[image: Detail of the keyhole domain in the proof of Cauchy integral theorem.]

For $\delta\to 0$, the two parallel segment parts of the keyhole domain $\Gamma_{\epsilon,\delta}$, having as endpoints respectively $z_1,z_2$ and $z_1-\delta\xi_1,z_2-\delta\xi_2$, tend to the same segment: since these two paths are traveled in opposite direction during the evaluation of the curvilinear integral \eqref{1} (as made explicit by equation \eqref{2}), their joint contribution tend to vanish and equation \eqref{3} holds.

Comment: Sorry Sir,But I do not Understand What is $z_1,z_2$ and other 2 symbol and Why This goes to zero?

Comment: @Shu I am drawing a picture in order to explain what I mean: basically, the four points are the

Comment: Thanks a Lot Sir...It is very Nice of you

Comment: @ShubhamRJ: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
0&=\lim_{\delta,\epsilon \to 0}\int_{\Gamma_{\delta,\epsilon}}F(\zeta)\,d\zeta\\
&= \int_{C}F(\zeta)\,d\zeta +\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{C_\epsilon}F(\zeta)\,d\zeta\\
&= \int_{C}F(\zeta)\,d\zeta +\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta - z}\,d\zeta +\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}\,d\zeta\\
&= \int_{C}F(\zeta)\,d\zeta + 0 -f(z)2\pi i\\
\end{align}$$
We thus conclude that $$2\pi i f(z) = \int_{C}F(\zeta)\,d\zeta= \int_{C}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}\,d\zeta$$
Which is the Cauchy Integral Formula.